# Workflow to model and texture a jigsaw puzzle

Tags: scripting, unity

## Goal

Create a repeatable workflow to model and texture different 500-5000+ piece jigsaw puzzles for use in Tabletop Simulator.

## Question

How would you model and texture a 500-5000+ piece jigsaw puzzle from a vector cut template appropriate for import into Tabletop Simulator / Unity.

I'm familiar with [Generating jigsaw pieces from svg curves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59086/generating-jigsaw-pieces-from-svg-curves) but think he quits just when it gets interesting.  Looking to move beyond 2d.  This is a complete, albeit small, puzzle cut template:

[image: 6x9 Jigsaw Piece Cut Template]

Edit: I removed my incomplete/attempted solution to reduce this to a single question.  Hope this is better.

Comment: Is this actually a question? What are you trying to ask here? Please limit it to one specific question. If you have multiple questions, please post each separately.

Comment: No, it's not a single question.  It's a broad request for help; I'm clearly lost.  I believe the goal is clear.  Is there a better place to post this?

Comment: Broad questions are not appreciated here. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59086/generating-jigsaw-pieces-from-svg-curves

Comment: Thank you for linking that.  I didn't have enough reputation to do it myself.  It was my hope that this picks up where you left off.

Comment: You can post this on [blenderartist.org](https://blenderartists.org) (i think).

Comment: The question would be more clear and specific if you [edit] it with screenshots of example vector templates, objects you created etc. If any part of the linked answer isn't clear you should point out more concretely what exactly, show the steps you've done and the step you're stuck on

Comment: I had as many links and attachments in the original question that I could (two, thanks stack exchange).  I removed them because they were part of my incomplete solution.  Which I'd gladly post again as an answer (though probably completely misguided; I came here for help), but stack exchange won't let me.  Can't include them because it's too broad.  Shouldn't remove them because it provides context for the question.  Argh.

Answer (score 1):

"How would one go about projecting an image across all these individual piece objects? That then get baked into textures? That can then be applied in TTS?"

I would just use the single image as the texture, and each piece would start out being in the same object mesh so that they can all be unwrapped from view at the same time and carry the same material - then you can separate each separate piece with P - 'separate by loose parts'. No baking needed.

Incidentally, I advise you to increase the resolution of your curve object before converting to mesh if you are concerned about the edges of each piece.

Comment: I had been reluctant to join the meshes only to separate them later.  I worried that it might be a lossy/approximate operation.  Once they're in the same mesh, you just UV unwrap the mesh, apply the image as a texture, then separate again?

Comment: Yes, I suggest trying it on a simpler project as a proof of concept first so that you make sure it will work for you. Join, uv project, and then separate.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing what I want/expect.  If I open  extrudedpuzzlecutascurves.blend, box select the curves, convert to mesh, join, separate by loose parts, I go from 54 objects to 162.  That's without even trying to texture anything.

Comment: Have all of the pieces be UV unwrapped, then use the UV project modifier.