# Boolean Difference subtracts empty areas

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, extrude, svg

I'm trying to create a jigsaw puzzle from a 3d terrain by subtracting a "die" but instead of leaving the puzzle pieces behind, it erases the whole puzzle as seen in the linked blender file below.  The die was converted to mesh from a curve that was extruded and solidified using a modifier.

[Blender File](https://easyupload.io/oa5doa)

[image: Screenshot Cutter]

[image: Screenshot Missing Puzzle Pieces]

Comment: Please add screenshots

Comment: Booleans need solid geometry to work. I think Blender is assuming your cutter is intended to be a single solid. Really interesting idea, but I'm not sure Boolean is the tool to make it work.

Comment: @RonJensen it looks like he has solidified the puzzle piece cutter, just barely, so I expected it to work.

Comment: @TheLabCat That is correct and the cutter is a single piece

Comment: I tried to convert my curve to mesh before extruding and merge by distance to remove double nodes and then convert back to curve (then extrude, solidify and back again to mesh) but Blender now crashes instead when I do the Boolean Difference.

Comment: Maybe I could simply use the curve and the knife tool, but I would need to be able to set the width of the cut because I plan on 3D-Printing this and I don't think that the pieces would properly fit together without any gaps.

Comment: Using Booleans for this is an unelegant and brute way to solve this. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59086/generating-jigsaw-pieces-from-svg-curves

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I don't see how you can set the knife width? It's the reason why I wasn't using it because I will print the puzzle and it needs a little gap to assemble easily.

Comment: Either bevel all edges afterwards, or design each piece as a bezier curve and use the *offset* property